# Как переопределять REDIRECT_URI для Laravel Socialite в зависимости от типа аутентифицирующегося пользователя?

Tags: laravel

Столкнулся с проблемой при аутентификации через соцсети для нескольких сущностей. Имеются две сущности: Student и Teacher. Для начала опишу рабочий вариант для одной сущности.
Мои роуты аутентификации:

```
//Socialite auth routes...
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'SocialController@index')->name('auth.provider');
    Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'SocialController@callback');
});
```

Мой контроллер:

```
class SocialController extends Controller
{
    public function index($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function callback(SocialService $socialService, $provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        if ($u = $socialService->saveSocialData($user)) {
            Auth::guard('student')->login($u);
            return redirect()->route('profile.index');
        }

        return back();
    }
}
```

Мой конфиг :

```
VKONTAKTE_CLIENT_ID=7864077
VKONTAKTE_CLIENT_SECRET=Z2i92xXe47mGJY3D5DQE
VKONTAKTE_REDIRECT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/vkontakte/callback
```

Так все прекрасно работает, но для сущности Student.
Я хочу передавать в параметр маршрута еще и название сущности (для выбора соответствующей модели, гварда и редиректа в контроллере), вот так в переменную $client:

```
//Socialite auth routes...
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('auth/{client}/{provider}', 'SocialController@index')->name('auth.provider');
    Route::get('auth/{client}/{provider}/callback', 'SocialController@callback');
});
```

Но, я сталкиваюсь с проблемой конфигурации маршрута REDIRECT_URI:

```
VKONTAKTE_REDIRECT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/student/vkontakte/callback
VKONTAKTE_REDIRECT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/teacher/vkontakte/callback
```

Если я пропишу два маршрута в конфиге, то переменная просто переопределится и вернет всегда последний маршрут для любой сущности.
Как можно динамически изменять REDIRECT_URI в зависимости от передаваемых параметров?

Answer (score 0):

Можно [переопределять конфиг](https://socialiteproviders.com/usage/#overriding-a-config) из кода.

Т.е в Вашем `index` проверяйте, кому нужно войти, и подставляйте в конфиг редирект (если путь указан в приложении ВК, конечно).

```
$redirectUrl = "http://yourdomain.com/api/redirect";
$config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config(env('VKONTAKTE_CLIENT_ID'), env('VKONTAKTE_CLIENT_SECRET'), $redirectUrl);
return Socialite::driver($provider)->setConfig($config)->redirect();
```